# Calling an object function if it exists in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am implementing a binary search tree class in `Typescript` as an exercise to learn the language, and I'm trying to make it using `generics`.

In the algorithms of the class I've implemented so far, I'll need to do two logical operations with whatever object I'm dealing with: Check if they're equal, and check of one is greater than the other.
This is easy when manipulating primitive types like `number`, since I can just use the operators `===` and `>` to compare the objects, but as I want to make a generic class, things start to get complicated here.

In order to achieve this, I came up with this "solution", where the user's object need to have two methods defined: `equals` and `greaterThan`. Based on that, I created this code for my tree's node:

```
class TreeNode<T> {
  /* A node used in the tree. */
  data: T;
  left: TreeNode<T> | undefined;
  right: TreeNode<T> | undefined;

  constructor(data: T) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = undefined;
    this.right = undefined;
  }

  equals(obj: TreeNode<T>): boolean {
    /* Checks whether an equals function exists in the object. If it doesnt,
    tries to use === operator to perform equality check instead. */

    if ('equals' in obj.data)
      return <boolean>this.data.equals(obj.data);
    else
      return this.data === obj.data;
  }

  greaterThan(obj: TreeNode<T>): boolean {
    /* Checks whether an greaterThan function exists in the object. If it doesnt,
    tries to use > operator to check if this.data is greater than obj.data */

    if ('greaterThan' in obj.data)
      return <boolean>this.data.greaterThan(obj.data);
    else
      return this.data > obj.data;
  }
}
```

As you can see, my code is meant to compare the nodes(the `TreeNode`'s functions `equals` and `greaterThan` will be called by the `BinarySearchTree` class, which I hadn't included here), and when comparing the nodes, it will check whether the mentioned methods are defined in the user's object, stored in the `data` attribute. If they are, I'll use them to compare. If they aren't, I'll assume that the object is a number, using the relational operators instead.
Happy with my solution, I tried to compile the code, which resulted in the following errors:

> TS2339: Property 'equals' does not exist on type 'T'.
>
> TS2339: Property 'greaterThan' does not exist on type 'T'.

So, even though I've checked if the methods exists, the compiler refuses to compile the code. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a type constrain for `T` and have the two members as optional:

```
class TreeNode<T extends { equals?(o: T): boolean; greaterThan?(o: T): boolean }> {
    /* A node used in the tree. */
    data: T;
    left: TreeNode<T> | undefined;
    right: TreeNode<T> | undefined;

    constructor(data: T) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = undefined;
        this.right = undefined;
    }

    equals(obj: TreeNode<T>): boolean {
        /* Checks whether an equals function exists in the object. If it doesnt,
        tries to use === operator to perform equality check instead. */

        if (this.data.equals)
            return <boolean>this.data.equals(obj.data);
        else
            return this.data === obj.data;
    }

    greaterThan(obj: TreeNode<T>): boolean {
        /* Checks whether an greaterThan function exists in the object. If it doesnt,
        tries to use > operator to check if this.data is greater than obj.data */

        if (this.data.greaterThan)
            return <boolean>this.data.greaterThan(obj.data);
        else
            return this.data > obj.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I modified your solution a little bit. I've changed the declaration of `TreeNode`, putting the extra properties in a separated `interface`, doing  `TreeNode<T>`, and then used the intersection type `data: T & NodeData<T>;` when declaring the attribute. I was stuck here because I didin't realize that you can name your functions in interfaces, as the docs weren't really clear about that. Another thing was the conditionals to verify if the attribute exists, mine were different and they won't work in this situation.